# variable not expanding in cURL option

Tags: bash, variables, curl, variable-expansion

Can's seem to get a variable to expand within a cURL option.

I've tried various approaches including the following:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9047/api/v3/sql \
-H 'Authorization: ${mytoken} ' \

curl -X POST http://localhost:9047/api/v3/sql \
-H 'Authorization: "'"$mytoken"'" ' \
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: you need to wrap the WHOLE string in double quotes in stead of single quote: `"Authorization: ${mytoken}"`. You seem to have the right idea in the second example, but since it is inside the outer string literal bash does not treat it as an expansion

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Thanks Josh, that worked like a champ!  Cyrus, appreciate you providing that link -- that was the best thread I've seen explaining the differences between single and double quotes.